# I want my pictures to go to Windows Live Media not to One Drive. How do I change that?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, photos

One Drive keeps putting my photos downloaded or uploaded into One Drive. I want my pictures to go to my Windows Live Media where I have all my other pictures. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like all the Windows Live services, including the media services, are being, or already have been, retired by Microsoft. OneDrive is replacing the service you are using.

> OneDrive is included in the suite of online services formerly known as Windows Live.

<sub>([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OneDrive))</sub>

There is a list of the discontinued Windows Live products on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live#Discontinued_services) with the final services relating to OneDrive ceasing in 2012.

The good news is that all your previous images should have [migrated](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/onedrive/skydrive-to-onedrive) to the new system.